# VBA code to change date format after copying date/time from Excel to text file

Tags: vba

I wrote a very simple VBA code that copies some data (Date/time and numbers) from Excel and copies them into a predefined format in a TEXT file. Below is the code I wrote. It serves what I wanted it to do. The only issue is that in Excel, the date format is "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" and in TEXT format, I want to change that format to "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss". I changed the date/column format to the desired format in Excel but it keeps copying the same old format.

```
Sub CopyDataFromExcelToTextFile()

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
Dim r As Variant

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\Users\UserName\TEXTFILE.txt")

Sheet1.Activate
' Column A contains date/time data
' all other columns contain numbers

For Each r In Range("A6", Range("A5").End(xlDown))

    ts.Write ("DATES")
    ts.WriteLine
    ts.Write r.Value & " /"
    ts.WriteLine
    ts.WriteLine ("/")
    ts.WriteLine
    ts.Write ("ABCDE")
    ts.WriteLine
    ts.Write ("EFGH" & " IJKL" & " MNOP" & " " & r.Cells(1, 6) & " 1* " & r.Cells(1, 4) & " 2* " & r.Cells(1, 7) & " " & r.Cells(1, 2) & " /")
    ts.WriteLine
    ts.WriteLine ("/")
    ts.WriteLine

Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does your code try changing the Date format?

Comment: If you take the cells *Value* then you get the underlying numeric date without any formatting.  Either take the cells *Text* or take the value and use `Format()` to make it look how you want.

Comment: @ Tim Williams: thanks for the hint. With Format() it works